# Read input from istream until EOF

Tags: c++, input

I am having trouble understanding how to read from istream for my code. The program assignment I am trying to do is retrieve input from user or from an input file from the cmdline (ie. ./ < input.txt). The user input values are passed to a function that determines if it is a prime number or not. The issue is when I pass an input file (ie. input.txt) with multiple integers or characters, it only reads the first one and the program ends. I have read many questions and answers, but many of the solutions I have tried do not work.

For example, input.txt holds:

```
2 3 4 5
```

or

```
2
3
4
5
```

Here is my program, I won't provide my isPrime function as I believe it working just fine. It is just the issue with passing the input file to be read until end-of-file. Should I be using ifstream isntead? I was given a hint to use a while loop to read till end-of-file but that just keeps spitting the same first data I input in the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int) { // Example return for isPrime
        return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        // Initialize input integer
        int num = 0;

        cout << "Enter number to check if prime: ";
        cin >> num;

        // while loop to detect bad input
        while(!(cin >> num)){
                cin.clear(); // clear error flag
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //ignores bad input
        } // end while

        while(cin >> num){ // while there is valid input, do isPrime
            if(isPrime(num)){
                    cout << "prime\n";
            } else {
                    cout << "composite\n";
            }
        } // end while
        return 0;

} // end main
```

Comment: "it only reads the first one and the program ends." Does it *really* read the first one? Better check what's the value of `num` before passing it to `isPrime` ;) Moreover, why do you expect your program to process all numbers? How often do you call `isPrime`? Is it in a loop?

Comment: You need to put a loop around the whole thing, and check `cin.eof()`

Comment: @DanielJour Previously I had it printing the value that was being passed to  num. I do not expect my program to process all the numbers (ie. if there is an invalid input such as "a" then it should throw an error). isPrime is only called once but expected to process all the inputs given to it.

Comment: @Barmar Could you clarify what I am encasing with `cin.eof`?

Comment: When `cin >> num` fails, you can use `if(cin.eof()) exit()` to end the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `while` loop incorrectly.

Use:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int num = 0;

   // Keep reading from stdin until EOF is reached or
   // there is bad data in the input stream.
   while ( cin >> num )
   {
      if(isPrime(num)){
         cout << "prime\n";
      } else {
         cout << "composite\n";
      }
   }

   return 0;

} // end main
```

Comment: I have implemented it this way, however when I execute it still is only reading the first data input still. Alternatively, when I change `num` to type `char` it happens to read through the file but give invalid results.

Comment: He seems to want to skip over bad data, not stop when he gets it.

Comment: @JaayW, if you want to be able to handle bad data by skipping the test of the line and stop only when EOF is reached, you have to use a different strategy. Is that your intention?